# Why fetching data from sqlite block Node.JS?

Tags: performance, node.js, sqlite, sql-order-by

I want to fetch and export to csv file huge amount (5 - 12 milions rows) of archive data from Sqlite database. While doing this the whole server is blocked. No other connection can be handled by server (for example I couldn't open website in another tab in browser).

Node.JS server part:

```
function exportArchiveData(response, query){                                                                                                    
  response.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/csv');                             
  response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=archive.csv');                      
  db.fetchAllArchiveData(                                                     
      query.ID,                                                               
      function(error, data){
          if(!error)                                           
             response.write(data.A + ';' + data.B + ';' + data.C + '\n');           
      },                                                                      
      function(error, retrievedRows){
          response.end();                                                     
      });                                                                     
};
```

Sqlite DB module:

```
 module.exports.SS.prototype.fetchAllArchiveData = function (          
     a, callback, complete) {                                                  

     var self = this;                                                            

 //      self.sensorSqliteDb.all(                                                
         self.sensorSqliteDb.each(                                               
             'SELECT A, B, C '+                            
             'FROM AD WHERE '+                                          
             ' A="' + a + '"'+                                                
             ' ORDER BY C ASC' +                                         
             ';'                                                                 
             ,
             callback,                                                               
             complete                                                            
         );                                                                      
 };
```

I also create index on AD like CREATE INDEX IAD ON AD(A, C) and EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN show that this index is used by sqlite engine.

Still, when I call exportArchiveData server send the data properly but no other action can be performed during this. I have a huge amount of data (5 - 12 milions of rows to send) so it takes ~3 minutes.

**How can I prevent this from blocking whole server?**

I thought that if I use EACH and there will be callback's the server will be more responsive. Also Memory usage is huge (about 3GB and even more). Can I prevent this somehow?

*In answer to comments, I would like to add some clarifications:*

I use [node-sqlite3 from developmentseed](https://npmjs.org/package/sqlite3). It should be asynchronous and non-blocking. And it is. When statement is prepared I can request main page. But when server start serving data, then Node.js server is blocked. I guess thats because request for home page is one request to call some callback while there are milions request for callback handling archive data "EACH".

If I use sqlite3 tool from linux command line I do not get rows immediately but that is not the problem as long as node-sqlite3 is non-blocking.

Yes. I'm hitting CPU max. What is worse, when I request twice as much data the whole memory is used, and then server freeze forever.

Comment: It's possible it needs all 3 minutes to apply the ORDER BY before it can start return any data at all.  Do you have an index on your table for column C?

Comment: Yes, I have (but it is not used according to EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN). I also tried this query without ORDER BY and it took only ~30s less. But still over 3 minutes and still blocking server

Comment: Do you have an index on A?  If you run your query in some other tool, does it also take that long to get data back?  If you remove the WHERE and ORDER BY do you start getting data back immediately without blocking?  If that's true, the problem is much more likely your DB/tuning than the Node code.

Comment: Although node is async, there's a chance you're hitting your cpu max. Remember, node runs on a single core, so it's not multithreaded. Also, that's quite a huge callback. If you really needed to get that much data, it would be best to have a node server on the other end that get's 200 at a time or something. Lastly, SQLite is a file db and won't queue requests like MySQL or Postres can. You can actually pipe your SQLite db into a MySQL db which might offer more performance. So if that's the goal, you may as well do that.

Comment: film42, I don't get what you mean by 200. You mean http response code?  JOE, yes I've index on A because it's a PrimaryKey. For your other questions I've tried to answer in addition to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I handle this problem this way.

Instead of using Database#each I use Database#prepare with multiple Statement#get.

What is more, I investigate that running out of memory was caused by full buffer of response. So now, I call for next row when I get previous and when response buffer have place for new data. Working perfect. And Now server is not blocked (only during preparing statement).

Sqlite module:

```
module.exports.SS.prototype.fetchAllArchiveData = function (                  
 a) {                                                          

 var self = this;                                                                    
 var statement = self.Db.prepare(                                                                                          
         'SELECT A, B, C '+                                    
         'FROM AD WHERE '+                                                  
         ' A="' + a + '"'+                                                        
         ' ORDER BY C ASC' +                                                 
         ';'                                                                         
         ,                                                                           
         function(error){                                                            
             if(error != null){                                                      
                 console.log(error);                                                 
             }                                                                       
         }                                                                                                                                           
     );                                                                              
 return statement;                                                                   
};
```

Server side:

```
function exportArchiveData(response, query){                                    

 var respRet = null;                                                         
 var i = 0;                                                                  
 var statement = db.fetchAllArchiveData(                                     
     query.ID);                                                               
 var getcallback = function(err, row){                                       
     if(err != null){                                                        
         console.mylog(err);                                                 
         return;                                                             
     }                                                                       
     if(typeof(row) != 'undefined'){                                         
         respRet = response.write(row.A + ';' + row.B + ';' + row.C + '\n');
         console.log(i++ + ' ' + respRet);                                   
         if(respRet){                                                        
             statement.get(getcallback);                                     
         }else{                                                              
             console.log('should wait on drain');                            
             response.on('drain', function(){                                
                 console.log('drain - set on drain to null, call statement');
                 response.on('drain', function(){});                         
                 statement.get(getcallback);                                 
             });                                                             
         }                                                                   
     }else{                                                                  
         response.end();                                                     
     }                                                                       
 };                                                                          

 statement.get(function(err, row){                                           
     response.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/csv');                         
     response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=archive.csv');                   
     getcallback(err, row);                                                  
 });                                                                         
 };
```

Comment: In fact response.on('drain'...) should be defined only once. This solution provides to memory leak as many event listeners are created. Just define this response.on once and create some stopFlag when onDrain should call statement.get.